# A delta integral with two added functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

I have an integral I need to evaluate as far as possible that contains the delta function, and I haven't been able to solve it the way I usually do. Here it is:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\ \delta(x-\pi)sin(x)f(x)$$

Assuming that $f(x)$ is a general smooth (infinitely differentiable) function.

The way I have been solving these is using substitution, and here is my attempt at solving this problem:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\ \delta(g(x))sin(x)f(x)$$
$$g(x)=x-\pi=0 \\ x=\pi$$
$$y(x)=sin(x)f(x)$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\ \delta(g(x))sin(x)f(x)=\sum_{a<x_i<b,\ \ \ g(x_i)=0} {y(x_i)\over |g'(x_i)|}$$ 
$$g'(x)=1, \ \ g'(\pi)=1$$
$$y(\pi)=sin(\pi)f(\pi)=0$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\ \delta(g(x))sin(x)f(x)=0$$

Normally the formula I have been given is this:
$$\sum_{a<x_i<b,\ \ \ g(x_i)=0} {f(x_i)\over |g'(x_i)|}$$
but $f(x)$ was already in the integral and I thought it would be a good idea to combine the two of them together to make it into a form that I know how to solve.

This answer doesn't seem right to me. I would think that it wouldn't be $0$ because we are working with the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$ and not including $\pi$, which is the only place $sin(x)$ would be $0$. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Isn’t $\int dx \deta(x-a)f(x)$ just always $f(a)$? This we immediately get that it’s zero. I’m confused about why you’re doing this whole computation.

Comment: @StellaBiderman yes, but if it has boundaries it's different, and this has boundaries. Also this is $sin(x)f(x)$, not just $f(x)$.

Comment: I’m using $f$ differently from you. $f_{stella}(x)=\sin(x)f_{grace}(x)$. Sorry for the confusion. What do you mean by “has boundaries”?

Comment: Well from what I've learned is that if it's an indefinite integral the answer is just $f(a)$, but if the limits are say, $b<a<d$ then the solution is $f(a)$ only on that interval and elsewhere it is $0$.

Comment: What are b, a and d in this problem? @StellaBiderman is right. This integral is zero, an open-and-shut case.

Comment: @Mathemagical here it is $-\infty<x_i<\infty$, but okay. I suppose I'm overthinking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theorem:** Let $\delta$ denote the Dirac Delta function. Then for all $a$ and $f$, $\int_\mathbb R dx \delta(x-a)f(x)=f(a)$

From this, we immediately have that the answer is zero since $\sin(\pi)=0$.

I think you’re confused with when we integrate across a subset of the domain, call it $S$. In this case we have that $\int_S dx\delta(x-a)f(x)$ gives $f(a)$ if $a\in S$ and $0$ otherwise. However we aren’t considering an integral of this form, and even if we were $a$ lies inside the domain of the integral (since $\pi\in\mathbb R$) and even if it didn’t both options tell you the answer is $0$.

You’re way over complicating this.